# Autofac: How to get all registrations for a scope taking into account all the parent scopes?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I would like to get registrations for a scope, taking into account all parent scopes, to validate the container configuration according to some rules. The problem is that the following code only shows registrations for the last scope and doesn't account for the registrations of all parent scopes.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>();

using var container = builder.Build();
using var scope1 = container.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IBar>());
using var scope2 = scope1.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterType<Baz>().As<IBaz>());

var registrations = scope2.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
    .SelectMany(r => r.Services
        .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
        .Select(s => $"{s.ServiceType} -> {r.Activator.LimitType}"));

foreach (var registration in registrations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(registration);
}

// Output:
// Sandbox.IBaz -> Sandbox.Baz
```

Note #1: I'm using Autofac `4.9.4`.

Note #2: There is a source of the [ExternalRegistrySource](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/src/Autofac/Core/Registration/ExternalRegistrySource.cs#L40) internal Autofac's type in the `scope.ComponentRegistry.Sources` that contains a private field `IComponentRegistry _registry`. This field contains the registration of the parent scope, but this approach requires reflection and I'd like to know if there is a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found a better solution:

```
static IEnumerable<ILifetimeScope> GetAllScopes(ILifetimeScope scope)
{
    yield return scope;

    if (scope is ISharingLifetimeScope sharingLifetimeScope)
    {
        while (sharingLifetimeScope.ParentLifetimeScope != null)
        {
            yield return sharingLifetimeScope.ParentLifetimeScope;
            sharingLifetimeScope = sharingLifetimeScope.ParentLifetimeScope;
        }
    }
}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>();

using var container = builder.Build();
using var scope1 = container.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterType<Bar>().As<IBar>());
using var scope2 = scope1.BeginLifetimeScope(c => c.RegisterType<Baz>().As<IBaz>());

var registrations = GetAllScopes(scope2)
    .SelectMany(s => s.ComponentRegistry.Registrations)
    .SelectMany(r => r.Services
        .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
        .Select(s => $"{s.ServiceType} -> {r.Activator.LimitType}"));

foreach (var registration in registrations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(registration);
}

// Output:
// Sandbox.IBaz -> Sandbox.Baz
// Sandbox.IBar -> Sandbox.Bar
// Autofac.ILifetimeScope -> Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope
// Autofac.IComponentContext -> Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope
// Sandbox.IFoo -> Sandbox.Foo
```